# c# student registration system help linked to a SQL database

Tags: c#, sql

Please help with this coding error? I am new to C# and SQL and need some fast help.

This is the code I have already, the problem comes when I debug it throws an error when I get to

```
string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                              .ConnectionStrings["Student1"]
                              .ConnectionString;
```

The error message is

> null reference exception was unhandled.

No matter what I do I can't seem to fix this error. Any ideas?

```
static class Program
public static SqlConnection GetConnection
{
    get
    {
        string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                                      .ConnectionStrings["Student1"]
                                      .ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        return con;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post your App.config too.

Comment: Is there a connection string called `Student1` in your app.config?

Answer (score 3):

You must  verify that you have connection string in your configuration file

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Student1"
         connectionString="...."
         providerName="...." />
  </connectionStrings>
  ....
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer(s) it might be worth pointing out why you get this error.

Basically your code here:

```
string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Student1"].ConnectionString;
```

Is trying to access the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` collection, the indexer for this collection returns a NULL if no value is found (some other collections will raise an index out of range exception)

It is likely the value is NULL because you are missing the connection string from your app.config - but since you aren't checking to see if the connection string object returned by the indexer is null and you are trying to use it's value, a null reference exception is thrown

A good check would be:

```
var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Student1"];

if(conn == null) throw new Exception("No connection string in config file"); // etc

string ConnectionString = conn.ConnectionString;
```

This way you could throw a more meaningful exception if the connection string was absent